# Why is a conversion operator not called when using initialization syntax, and why does the clang error message seem wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, implicit-conversion, copy-initialization

I have the following code, which constructs one object t2 using a explicit conversion constructor, which performs an implicit conversion of t1. This is expected, and is described in The C++ Programming Language, in section 11.4.1 of the 3rd edition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class test1 {
public:
    test1() {}
    operator string() {
        cout << "test1 string conversion operator called" << endl;
        return string();
    }
};
class test2 {
public:
    test2() {}
    test2(string s) {
        cout << "test2 string conversion constructor called" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    test1 t1;
    test2 t2(t1);
    return 0;
}
```

And as you would expect:

```
> clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Thread model: posix
> clang++ -std=c++11 test.cc
> ./a.out
test1 string conversion operator called
test2 string conversion constructor called
```

However, when changing t2's construction to initialization syntax:

```
test1 t1;
test2 t2 = t1;
return 0;
```

Clang outputs the following:

```
test.cc:23:15: error: no viable conversion from 'test1' to 'test2'
        test2 t2 = t1;
              ^    ~~
test.cc:13:11: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'test1' to 'const test2 &' for 1st argument
    class test2 {
          ^
test.cc:13:11: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'test1' to 'test2 &&' for 1st argument
    class test2 {
          ^
test.cc:16:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'test1' to 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') for 1st argument
        test2(string s) {
        ^
test.cc:8:9: note: candidate function
        operator string() {
        ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't know if initialization is supposed to be able to perform an implicit conversion like this, but the error message seems very very wrong. **no known conversion from 'test1' to 'string'**, yet it even shows **candidate function operator string() {**

What gives? And what does the C++ standard say about implicit conversions in initialization constructors? I *assume* that this should be counted as two implicit conversions, and thus not allowed, but the compiler output doesn't suggest that at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, it's wrong to call `test2::test2(string)` an *"explicit conversion constructor"*. It'll be used in implicit conversions (mark it `explicit` if you don't want that).

Anyway, clang's error message is spot on and it almost perfectly explains what's going on.
This:

```
test2 t2(t1);
```

is called *direct initialization*. All constructors for `test2` are candidates and additionaly, compiler can run an implicit conversions sequence to match the arguments. It finds `test1::operator string` and `test2::test(string)` and all is well.

This:

```
test2 t2 = t1;
```

is called *copy initialization*. The expression on the right of `=` needs to be converted to `test2` and then either a copy- or move-constructor will be called to construct the object (in theory at least, it can later be elided as an optimization, but it must be accessible nonetheless).

Comment: Why does the notes say there is no known conversion though? The bold text is what I find most confusing. Like, it says in the note that the string conversion constructor is not viable **because there is no way to convert test1 to string**. But there is.

Comment: So, it can't convert t1 to t2 without using two implicit conversions, the implicit test1->string and the implicit conversion from copy initialization. But the compiler output suggests it tried to double convert and couldn't find the test1->string conversion. Is it just wrong?

Comment: Hm, on second reading, it is indeed confusing and looks wrong. I'm no authority to critique clang developers, though and also can't say why they chose this kind of error here.

Comment: Okay. That's good to know. I was thinking it was correct and I was not understanding something.

Comment: @peter Note that there *can* be two implicit conversion, it's just that only one can be user defined. In `test2 t2 = t1` there is one user defined conversion (via `test2::test(string)`). It there were a standard conversion sequence needed, it would be ok. But it's not, it needs `operator string`. So the compiler does see it, but it's not viable. Maybe that's the reason for the error message.