# clang error : note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable:

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, sfinae, clang++

I have a following use case which is causing clang to emit errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A
{
    public:
        int x;
        A(int g):x(g){}
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        int y;
        B(int p):A(p),y(p) {}
};

class Holder
{
    template<typename T>
        Holder(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,A>::value
                     && std::is_base_of< A , T>::value >::type&& val)
        : b (std::forward<T>(val))
        {}


    private:
        B b;
};

int main()
{
    B b(10);

    Holder h(b);
}
```

The error is as follows

```
forward.cpp:35:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Holder'
    Holder h(b);
           ^ ~
forward.cpp:18:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'B' to 'const Holder' for 1st argument
class Holder
      ^
forward.cpp:18:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'B' to 'Holder' for 1st argument
class Holder
      ^
forward.cpp:21:9: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
        Holder(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,A>::value
        ^
1 error generated.
```

when compiled with `clang++ --std=c++11 forward.cpp`.

What am I missing here?

I have already consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008689/why-is-a-conversion-operator-not-called-when-using-initialization-syntax-and-wh) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457370/c-constructor-calling-and-object-creation) questions, however they didnt seem to solve my use case.

Comment: The important message is the last one. The compiler can't infer T.

Comment: You should read about [non-deduced context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context?lq=1) to see why the compiler cannot deduce `T` from `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to specify the second parameter of `std::enable_if` (which defaults to `void`)

```
template<typename T>
Holder(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, A>::value
                 && std::is_base_of< A , T>::value, T>::type&& val)
    : b (std::forward<T>(val))
    {}
```

But anyway, `T` would be in a non deducible context.
You may do

```
template<typename T>
Holder(T&& val,
       typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, A>::value
                               && std::is_base_of<A, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value,
                               std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr)
    : b (std::forward<T>(val))
    {}
```

or

```
template<typename T,
         typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, A>::value
                               && std::is_base_of<A, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value,
                               std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>
Holder(T&& val)
    : b (std::forward<T>(val))
    {}
```